# Is there a way in Windows 7 to create a shortcut to a command-line (console) application and leave the command window open?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, shortcuts

There are a number of console type applications, e.g. ipconfig, that output information to the standard output.

The problem is that if I create a windows shortcut to them it runs the command and closes the console window before I can read the output.

I realize that I could create a batch file with a pause command and then make the shortcut go to that batch file, but I was wondering if there was any generic way I could configure a shortcut to a console/command-line type program to leave the window open until the user explicitly closes it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13746246/447599

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use cmd.exe

```
cmd /k ipconfig
cmd /k ping google.com
cmd /k etc..........
```

command line does NOT go away until you exit it.

Comment: Tough to pick a winner on this one because all of these answers work, but I'm going with this one because it is the simplest of the approaches offered.

Comment: @JohnFx: In the meanwhile there is a [better solution](http://superuser.com/a/175523/176568) which is just as simple.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can't. I thought there was an option to set, but on Windows Seven, I cannot find anything like this.

Like you said, the easiest way is to make a batch file. Note that you can make it perfectly generic. Create a file `generic.bat` containing:

```
%1
pause
```

then call it with a shortcut:

```
generic.bat ipconfig
```

Comment: That's a really good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `/c` option with `cmd.exe` like so:

```
%COMSPEC% /c ipconfig&&pause
```

Comment: IMHO the best solution, but doesn't work if the first command signals an error (through a non-zero exit code). This only works when using a single ampersand: `%COMSPEC% /c <command> & pause`

Comment: Anyone wondering why you need `cmd /c`: to interpret the `&` syntax. The standard Windows shortcut is not a command line so we need to wrap it.